# How to add my photostream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr, photostream

I want to add my photostream to my website I have tried multiple bits of code

https://gist.github.com/willdurand/5705453 (cant find the set id)

and

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=675729@N22&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
  jQuery.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    jQuery("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images")
      .wrap("<a href='" + item.link + "'></a>");
  });
});
```

suppose I need to find id to add the public feed to my photostream?

edit this seems to work but throws a 403.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    var apikey = 'xxxxxxx';
    var userid = 'xxxxxx';
    jQuery.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key='+apikey+'&user_id='+userid+'&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    function(data){
       jQuery.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
            var purl = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_m.jpg';
            var pid = item.id;
            var container = '<div class="image-container" style="background: url(' + purl+ ');"></div>';
           jQuery(container).appendTo('#images');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this works just have to set the images to public.

Comment: What is the problem you are receiving? There is no question here?

Comment: This works for me? Whats the error? http://jsfiddle.net/mYnQy/

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the exact code you have posted below and applied it to a JSFiddle.

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=675729@N22&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
  jQuery.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    jQuery("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images")
      .wrap("<a href='" + item.link + "'></a>");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYnQy/

The images are returned correctly and the links are working too, I would imagine that you should check that you have a div with an ID of "images" located on your page and that you have no other javascript that is causing an error on your page.

Check this by using developer tools in your browser of choice and taking a look at the Console.

Comment: yes but it doesn't add my stream - suppose what I am asking is how to find my photostream id

Comment: How about you edit your question to actually explain that this is the problem?